# Gym TransformationObservation wrapper seems not to transform the observation space

Tags: python, transform, wrapper, environment

currently I'm trying to set up an environment to train a neuronal network with python and gym. I would like to use an one-hot encoded observation space, but rather using the values -1 and 1 instead of 0 and 1. So I tried to transform a MultiDiscrete observation space with the funktion "transform" that leaves the ones unchanged and transforms the zeros into -1. But when i apply the wrapper TransformationObservation to my MultiDiscrete observation using my transform function, it seems to have no impact on the observation space. Interestingly I do not get any errors. The function just leaves to obervation space unchanged. I am new setting up environments and doing something with neuronal networks and I'm sure that the solution is quite simple, but at the moment I'm stuck here. Googling and searching hasn't lead to the solution yet.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here ist my code that I tried:

```
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import MultiDiscrete
from gym.wrappers import TransformObservation, FlattenObservation
import numpy as np
import random as rd

class Test_Env(Env): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = MultiDiscrete(np.repeat(3, 118))
        self.observation_space = MultiDiscrete(np.repeat(2, 118))
        self.state = np.array(np.zeros(118))
        self.test_begin = 7
    def step(self, action):
        self.action = hot_encoding_action
        pass
    def render(self):
        pass
    def reset(self):
        self.state = np.array(np.zeros(2))
        self.test_begin = 7
        return self.state

env = Test_Env()
env.observation_space.sample()

array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64)

def transform(vec):
    new_vec =  vec*2-np.ones(118)
    return new_vec

wrapped_env = TransformObservation(env, transform)
wrapped_env.observation_space.sample()

array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Noone there who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the wrapper only affects the output observation, not the observation_space. ([https://gymnasium.farama.org/_modules/gymnasium/core/#RewardWrapper:~:text=class-,ObservationWrapper,-(Wrapper%5B)](https://gymnasium.farama.org/_modules/gymnasium/core/#RewardWrapper:%7E:text=class-,ObservationWrapper,-(Wrapper%5B))

I hope the following flow is helpful:

1. In the original environment:
   env -> generate observation -> check observation match observation_space -> observation
2. In the wrapper environment:
   env -> generate observation -> check observation match observation_space -> observation -> **f(observation)** -> **new observation**

Note: **f** is the wrapper function.